# How to properly manage Pipfile.lock

Tags: python, pipenv, devpi

This is my scenario:

- I am using `pipenv`
- I have private sources:

```
[[source]]
url = "http://devpi.mine/something/dev/+simple"
verify_ssl = false
name = "mysource"
```

- I have different environments: `dev` for development, with a private `devpi` where packages are upload, and `int` / `preprod` / `prod` with a shared `devpi`.
- Generating `Pipfile.lock` takes time (5min)

My problem: the `Pipfile.lock` that I am generating in `dev` is not usable in `int`, because the hashes do not match (different `devpi`)

Possible solutions:

1. Generate `Pipfile.lock.dev` and `Pipfile.lock.int`, and manage that myself (symlinks or renaming the file): a bit cumbersome
2. Generate `Pipfile.lock` as part of the release process: I don't like this because that means that `Pipfile.lock` is not used as reference, since each time it will be re-generated. Besides, this would slow down release.

Do you have any other idea how to manage different environments in the context of `pipenv`?